# How to send values through methods

Tags: java, methods

I am stumped trying to send a value through some methods as part of a question which reads

Write the following method: computeDiameter: This method accepts the radius (r) of a circle, and returns it's diameter (2*r)

It's under the "Passing values through different methods", so instead of asking me for a simple variable/formula like

```
double r;
double diameter = r*2; //along with Scanner and some System out prints
```

It's asking me to send the value of r through another method, then return the method and print out the new value for r. This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*; 
public class UserSquares
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int r = 2;
    int result=0; //I set result=0 hoping to initialize it properly. 
    computeDiameter(r);
    System.out.println(result);     
 }
public static int computeDiameter(int r)
  {
    int result = r * 2;
    return result;
  }
}
```

This question seemed very simple which is why i tried to tackle it. I know the basics of sending values through a method, but i don't know how to return them. I don't really have money for actual text books (so i settle for quizlet questions and stuff like that), and youtube videos don't help at all so I like coming to the forums to get help when I am really stumped but want to move on with other topics.

(this question is part of a java self test, just thought I should share that as I've asked a number of questions on this site and each time someone responds with something negatively as if I am trying to get you guys to complete my homework for me. I am not taking any Java classes, these questions are just self testing my skills so that when I do major in java programming after i finish highschool, I can have a pretty nice understanding of it. Again, this is not for a test, I am welcome to all types of explanations, as long as it is in the realm of comprehension for a beginner Java student. Please and thank you in advance)

EDIT: Thanks Guys. Immediately after I submitted this I worked on it some more and found a solution so i'll share it

new code

```
import java.util.*; 
 public class UserSquares
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int total, r = 2;
     total = computeDiameter(r);
     System.out.println(total);     
  }
 public static int computeDiameter(int value1)
   {
     int result;
     result = value1 * 2;
     return result;
   }
 }
```

EDIT #2: Holy crap I didn't expect to receive so many solutions so quick. Was about to answer it myself so that it would appear to be done. Sorry for the waste of your time guys, I will read every one of them to see the different solutions you guys offered and learn them so that your time isn't totally wasted. Thanks so much.

EDIT #3: Had a redundant line remaining from my first code that I forgot to take out that went through the compilation and didn't affect the outcome in anyway, but still decided to take it out. Thanks CodeMatrix!

Comment: Just edit the line `computeDiameter(r)` to `result = computeDiameter(r)` that will fix it. Because if you just name the return value inside the method result the result you declared above in the main method will never know what result comes out from the method.

Comment: The `result` in your `computeDiameter()` method is a local variable. So it is not visible outside of the method. The `result` in your `main` method is another local variable, only visible in the `main` method.

Comment: As said above; you assign 0 to `result`. Which is fine to initialise it. But you want then to change the value of `result` to the return value of your method. So therefore, `result = ...` will assign a new value to your variable, which in your case is the return value of `computeDiameter`. Just having `computeDiameter(r);` on its own does the calculation, but then does nothing with it. That's why you assign it to `result`.

Comment: CodeMatrix - Yeah I understood that after inputting different values and such. It hit me like a pile of bricks when I found out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Pieter - I figured returning the result would replace the variable value in the main method which would print it out. Boy was I wrong, and the realization came to me like knock out punch.

Comment: And btw you have no need to execute the `computeDiameter` method a second time after the initialization from the `result` variable in your main method :).

Comment: notyou - perfect explanation, and I realized it after i submitted it onto the forums. I had no idea what i was doing wrong, until i realized that they were local variables. Thank you for taking your time out to answer, I appreciate it from you all.

Comment: CodeMatrix (second comment) - AHH, I forgot to take that out from my first code. I had a feeling I had to take something out, but it compiled and worked so I just rolled with it.

Comment: @Jeff as you're new, take a quick read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: notyou -I would say thank you so much for redirecting me to the forum rules, but I see that's against the rules. I won't comment on my own question to thank someone anymore, so ill just nod to you with best wishes. (for real though, I'll stop from this day forward)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment section.

Go ahead and change this

```
int result = 0;
computeDiameter(r);
System.out.println(result);
```

to this

```
int result = 0; //or you use int result = computeDiameter(r);
result = computeDiameter(r); 
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

its very simple:

```
int result = computeDiameter(r);
```

or just

```
System.out.println(coputeDiameter(r));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value which is being returned from computeDiameter(r) method to the result variable in order to print that.

```
result = computeDiameter(r);
System.out.println(result);
```